Does a 2x2 study mean there are 4 groups or 2?
My study is a 2x2 design.
There are 2 IVs:
IV1 = sex (m/f) ;
IV2 = control / experimental groups.
Does this mean that I have 2 groups, and will therefore be using an independent T-Test, or i have 4 groups and will therefore use a one-way independent ANOVA? Or, because there is more than one IV, does this lead to a factorial independent measures ANOVA?
Any help is appreciated greatly!

This depends on what you're trying to answer.
There are technically 4 groups -- one for each combination of sex and exposure.  But how you go about analyzing these depends on your research question. Can you tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish?  What is your study about and what question are you trying to answer

The language here does get confusing!
You have two groups, in that very few people would think of "sex" as a group. On the other hand, you have a 2x2 design because you are, apparently, interested in both sex and group as a variable.
If you want to do ANOVA, then it is a two way ANOVA. Personally, I find the equivalent formulation as a multiple regression easier to work with, but that varies by person and field. They are mathematically the same, but programs will output the results in a different format.

Thank you so much for your response! My class material suggests that a multiple regression tends to be used in a study looking for predictors, whereas an ANOVA is used if looking for differences? And my initial proposal did not suggest sex as an IV, but I was suggested this design in feedback to my original draft, and as the feedback is from the person marking it, I thought it best to work with that. I didn't particularly understand sex being an IV either, I was originally just ensuring demographic data was collected so it could be accounted for as a potential confounding variable?

The class material isn't wrong, but you can find the differences through regression and you can find the predictors through ANOVA -- it's just a different format of output. Sex is find as an "IV" -- there is no mathematical difference between an IV and a confounding variable. The latter would just not be a focus of your analysis of the output.
